Create new column in dataframe based on regex pattern from different column
I have a dataframe with two columns, date of birth ("PN") (Swedish version YYMMDD-NNNN) and date of analysis. I would like to create a new column with only YYMMDD from the first one. But this column needs tidying up as some data contains mistakes including letters.
So my first thought was to filter out the correct data and use only those. But I realised I would prefer to keep all the data but create new columns, one for the YYMMDD "DOB" and one for data with mistakes "Problems".



PN
Analysis




800204-1567
240508


470205-1368
220608


550107-Y001
230608



I would like the results to be:



PN
Analysis
DOB
Problem




800204-1567
240508
800204
None


470205-1368
220608
470205
None


550107-Y001
230608
None
550107-Y001



So I would like to use some sort of test to see if the PN column matches a specific pattern:
DOB_pattern = r'(^\d{6})-(\d{4})'
I would like to use the regex to test the data in column "PN" and if it matches, copy over the first 6 digits. This means if it doesn't match, it needs to be something else I assume. But I can't figure out how to do this..
So should I create two new columns first with the result "None" and then replace this if it matches the pattern? How do I do this?
Somehow writing this in real code:
if row ("PN") == DOB_pattern, result ("DOB"): ("PN"){6}
else ("DOB") "None"
if row ("PN") != DOB_pattern, result ("Problem"): ("PN")
else ("Problem") "None"

You could use str.extract with your regex, and assign the first capturing group to "DOB', then identify the valid rows with notna and flag the others as "Problem" with mask:
DOB_pattern = r'(^\d{6})-(\d{4})'

df['DOB'] = df['PN'].str.extract(DOB_pattern)[0]
df['Problem'] = df['PN'].mask(df['DOB'].notna())

Variant with a unique capturing group:
df['DOB'] = df['PN'].str.extract(r'(^\d{6})-\d{4}', expand=False)
df['Problem'] = df['PN'].mask(df['DOB'].notna())

You could also craft a regex with a "catch-all" if the first part fails to perform the two steps with a unique str.extract:
df[['DOB', 'Problem']] = df['PN'].str.extract(r'(^\d{6})-\d{4}|(.*)')

regex demo
Output:
            PN  Analysis     DOB      Problem
0  800204-1567    240508  800204          NaN
1  470205-1368    220608  470205          NaN
2  550107-Y001    230608     NaN  550107-Y001

